# Using centroids to evaluate integral

Tags: integration

How can we use the centroids to evaluate integrals in general cases? Are there some theorems for it?
For example we know that 
$$\iint x dA = \bar x A$$
We can extrapolate this to include 
$$\iint (x +y )dA= \iint x dA + \iint ydA = (\bar x+\bar y) A$$
In the same manner we can also state 
$$\iint cx dA = c\bar x A$$

However, I can't figure out what will happen in cases where variables are being multipled or raised to a power. For example in cases 
$$\iint xy dA,\iint e^x dA $$ etc.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the story ends here. Integrals are linear operators so you can use the centroid for expressions like $\lambda x+\mu y$, but not more.

You can generalize to quadratic forms $\lambda x^2+2\mu xy+\nu y^2$ with the help of the moments of inertia (and similarly for higher order moments vs. higher degree polynomials).

For transcendental smooth functions, you can use the Taylor expansion and translate to *infinite* sums of moments. But there can be convergence issues.